# Group By syntax while using Cross Join

Tags: sql, group-by, cross-join

i wish to apply a Group By condition to my SQL below so that the O/P will display POL# with GP.

```
select t.POl#, (DEB.CUSTD - CRED.CUSTC) AS GP 
from (
        (
            select POL.SP_NUM POL#
            ,      sum(D.AMT) AS CUSTD 
            from   S_INVOICE D
            ,      S_ASSET POL 
            where  POL.ROW_ID           =   D.FN_ACCNT_ID 
            and    POL.SP_NUM           in  ('000','111','222') 
            and    D.DEBIT_TYPE         =   'Customer' 
            group by POL.SP_NUM
        ) DEB
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            select pol.SP_NUM POL#
            ,      sum(C.AMT) AS CUSTC 
            from   S_SRC_PAYMENT C
            ,      S_ASSET POL
            where  POL.ROW_ID           =   C.ASSET_ID 
            and    POL.SP_NUM           in  ('000','111','222') 
            and    C.CG_DEDN_TYPE_CD    =   'Customer' 
            group by POL.SP_NUM
        ) CRED
    ) t
    group by t.POL#
```

When i execute the same I am getting "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error, where the cursor points to 't'

Kindly assist.

```
Expected O/P:
POL#    GP
000     800
111     120
222     50
```

Appending Sample Data with explanation for better understanding of requirement:

Table 1:

```
S_ASSET
ROW_ID    POL#
1         000
2         111
3         222
4         333
5         444
```

Table 2:

```
S_INVOICE (Debit Table)
FN_ACCNT_ID    POL#    DEBIT_TYPE          AMT
1              000     Customer            10
1              000     Customer            10
1              000     Insurer             5
2              111     Customer            10
3              222     Customer            10
3              222     Insurer             5
5              444     Insurer             10
```

Table 3:

```
S_SRC_PAYMENT (Credit Table)
ASSET_ID    POL#    CG_DEDN_TYPE_CD     AMT
1           000     Insurer             10
1           000     Insurer             10
1           000     Customer            5
2           111     Insurer             10
3           222     Insurer             5
3           222     Insurer             5
3           222     Customer            5
5           444     Customer            10
```

As per this query I will consider "Customer" records per POL# and SUM the AMT. (Every Debit for the Customer will Credit Insurer(s) per POL# & vice-versa)

Expected O/P (Sum of Debits - Sum of Credits) for a Customer per POL#

```
POL #       AMT (GP)
000         15
111         10
222         5
333         0
444        -10
```

Comment: What is a unique key in S_ASSET? You are using the columns SP_NUM and ROW_ID. Is does one of them uniquely identify a record in the table? Maybe even both? Or maybe just the combination of the two?

Comment: unique key for S_ASSET will be ROW_ID, but for GROUPING SAKE SP_NUM will be considered as this will be duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously only want to get the deb and cred per s_asset and then aggregate so as to get the sums. You can do this without a join and subquery the sums directly instead:

```
select 
  sp_num as pol#,
  sum(<get deb sum for the pol.row_id here>) - sum(<get cred sum for the pol.row_id here>)
from s_asset pol 
where sp_num in ('000','111','222')
group by sp_num;
```

The complete query:

```
select 
  sp_num as pol#,
  coalesce(sum(
    (
      select sum(deb.amt)
      from s_invoice deb
      where deb.fn_accnt_id = pol.row_id
      and deb.debit_type = 'Customer' 
    )
  ), 0) -
  coalesce(sum(
    (
      select sum(cred.amt) 
      from s_src_payment cred
      where cred.asset_id = pol.row_id
      and cred.cg_dedn_type_cd = 'Customer' 
    ), 0)
  ) as gp
from s_asset pol 
where sp_num in ('000','111','222')
group by sp_num;
```

The same with joins instead:

```
select 
  pol.sp_num as pol#,
  coalesce(sum(deb.total), 0) - coalesce(sum(cred.total), 0) as gp
from s_asset pol
left join
(
  select fn_accnt_id as pol_row_id, sum(deb.amt) as total
  from s_invoice
  where  debit_type = 'Customer' 
  group by fn_accnt_id 
) deb on deb.pol_row_id = pol.row_id
left join
(
  select asset_id as pol_row_id, sum(amt) as total
  from s_src_payment
  where  cg_dedn_type_cd = 'Customer' 
  group by asset_id
) cred on cred.pol_row_id = pol.row_id
group by pol.sp_num;
```

Comment: wow!!...it will take me the next few hours to fully study & understand the query written by you. thank you so much. I will execute the same with complete columns and then mark your answer as correct/accepted.

Comment: umm...when there are no records in Credit &/or Debit tables for each POL, the result is not right. Count of records is correct, but GP is repeating the previous value where in it should be null/0...

Comment: That is strange. When there is no credit and/or debit record, then the sum is null. COALESCE changes null to zero. I see no way that a value gets repeated instead. Do you know sqlfiddle.com? There you can set up the tables with sample data. Try to find sample data that produces an unwanted result and give us the sqlfiddle link to check and verify.

Comment: Your syntax is completely correct. My test area has some junk data, I will create fresh meaningful records and validate the same. As for the sample data that I have shared, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax

```
from ( (select ...) CROSS JOIN (select ...) )
```

is invalid. A JOIN belongs to a FROM. So either of these would be correct:

```
from ( SELECT * FROM (select ...) CROSS JOIN (select ...) )
```

or

```
from (select ...) CROSS JOIN (select ...)
```

However, are you sure you want a CROSS JOIN at all? Both subqueries give you POL numbers plus data, bat rather than joining them on POL#, you cross join the results, so you get all POL# combinations instead.

Comment: Yes Thorsten, you are right. When I tested the query of more than one record it fails. I will update the thread with sample data so that you can understand my requirement. Maybe Cross Join is not needed at all.